# ARIMA Model Ljung-Box Test Derivation

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, arima, autocorrelation

Initially I am aware of the fact that in order to analyse autocorrelations of residuals of ARMA(p,q) we apply Ljung-Box test and involve chi-square distribution (because autocorrelations are asymptotically normally distributed) with degree of freedom n-p-q. I know the proof of autocorrelations are asymptotically normal but can not derive their sum of square have n-p-q degree of freedom. Could you please provide me with derivation of it?

Regards;

Comment: In time series, according to ljung-box there is a fact that  autocorrelations are normally distributed asymptotically and summation of autocorrelation of errors (such as lag 1, lag 2...) are chi square distribution. Wikipedia explains it.

Comment: I hope my question is explicit, I have not received any significant responses yet. Could you help me?

Comment: Is there anyone who may answer my question? I have not received any responses.......